# Cannot implement ZeroClipboard copy to clipboard directive in angular 1.2.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, zeroclipboard

```
app.directive('copyPost', ['$window', '$filter', 'ZeroClipboardPath', function ($window, $filter, ZeroClipboardPath) {
    return {
      scope: {
        postFn: '&',
      },
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        ZeroClipboardPath = ZeroClipboardPath || '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.min.js';
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard( angular.element(element), {
          moviePath: ZeroClipboardPath,
          trustedDomains: ['*'],
          allowScriptAccess: "always"          
        });
        clip.on('mousedown', function(client) {
          console.log('shit works');
          scope.postFn().then(function(data){
            client.setText(data.data[0].external_url);
          });  

        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

---

postFn gets the following function, which returns an HTTP promise(tested without the plugin, and the correct value is returned from the function into

```
jobsServ.shareObject = function(object, identifier, data){
        if(object == 'job')
            return $http.post(utils.getBaseUrl() + '/jobs/' + identifier + '/share', data, utils.getConfig());
        else if(object == 'company')
            return $http.post(utils.getBaseUrl() + '/companies/' + identifier + '/share', data, utils.getConfig());
    });
```

ZeroCLipboard script:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.min.js"></script>`

Problem: non of the ZeroCLipboard event are not firing.

Already attempted the following:
setting priority above 0(up to 100),
an incognito window with no adons (add block, etc),
using a local instance of the script and swf, and also the following settings:

tried using angular.element() and $() on the element, even tried to use an jquery css selector with an explicit id, but now luck.
Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's an Angular issue, so I'd recommend keeping the primary discussion on the GitHub issue you opened ([#283](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/issues/283)) rather than spreading it too thin... otherwise people on SO are going to be missing a lot of the details from the GitHub issue.

See my latest update on the GH issue for an identified potential error.  In particular:

If your `ZeroClipboardPath` argument is empty, the fallback isn't going to work because you're pointing the `moviePath` to a JS file rather than the Flash SWF:

`ZeroClipboardPath = ZeroClipboardPath || '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.min.js';`

Should be:

`ZeroClipboardPath = ZeroClipboardPath || '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zeroclipboard/1.1.7/ZeroClipboard.swf';`

Comment: This issue was solved, thank you, I didn't pay enoguht attention apparently, my bad.
Now I'm facing a different issue, a less obvious one, I believe:
`Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.`